# Qooxdoo discrepancy for setting maxWidth on SelectBox vs. VirtualSelectBox

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way to set the MaxWidth on the VirtualSelectBox Button, but not it's associated list?

The SelectBox seems to behave properly:
http://tinyurl.com/c5nhxb6

while the VirtualSelectBox does not:
http://tinyurl.com/bu2w3k8

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way I found was to override the auto adjustment from the drop-down. It's not a elegant way, but you can do this by setting the width when the drop-down appears:

```
var dropDown = selectBox.getChildControl("dropdown");
dropDown.addListener("appear", function() {
  this.setWidth(200);  
});
```

I would suggest to open an enhancement bug report, to address this feature for the future.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris, that worked like a charm! I'll open a ticket on that too.